# Fill empty missing dates in result from raw sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a query like the following that takes a `min_date` and `max_date`.

```
Select TO_CHAR(date_trunc('hour', table.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00') as formatted_date,
count(DISTINCT table.order_id) as unique_orders, sum(table.price) as total_price from table
where table.date>=min_date and table.date<=max_date

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).values.to_a
```

This will give me a count of the orders and the total price per "hour". For example, say this is my table

```
<id: 1, order_id: 1, date: 2020-06-10 10:18:01+00, price:10>
<id: 2, order_id: 1, date: 2020-06-10 10:43:19+00, price:14>
<id: 3, order_id: 2, date: 2020-06-10 12:10:00+00, price:15>
<id: 4, order_id: 3, date: 2020-06-10 12:20:21+00, price:10>
<id: 5, order_id: 3, date: 2020-06-10 14:10:54+00, price:20>
```

And my `min_date = 2020-06-10 09:00:00+00` and `max_date = 2020-06-10 14:00:00+00`. This would be my result:

```
[[2020-06-10 10:00, 1, 24], [2020-06-10 12:00, 2, 25], [2020-06-10 14:00, 1, 20]]
```

I want the missing hours in between the min_date and max_date to be included like so:

```
[[2020-06-10 09:00, 0, 0], [2020-06-10 10:00, 1, 24], [2020-06-10 11:00, 0, 0], [2020-06-10 12:00, 2, 25], [2020-06-10 13:00, 0, 0] [2020-06-10 14:00, 1, 20]]
```

So I want also all of the hours that are not present in the table but that is included in the time range between min_date and max_date. In this scenario, it's all the hours I want but it might be all the 'weeks' or 'months' depending on the argument I pass to `date_trunc`.

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN` with the result of a `generate_series` function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series()` to calculate all the dates you want.  Then use `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select to_char(gs.dte, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00') as formatted_date,
       count(distinct t.order_id) as unique_orders, sum(t.price) as total_price
from generate_series(min_date, max_date, interval '1 hour') gs(dte) left join
     table t
     on t.date >= gs.dte and
        t.date < gs.dte + interval '1 hour' and table.date<=max_date
group by gs.dte
order by gs.dte;
```